# Matlab/Simulink Build error: Unable to honor user-specified priorities

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

I try to generate code with the embedded matlab coder from a Simulink model.
Then this error occurs: Unable to honor user-specified priorities.
It seems to me that this algebraic loop triggers this error. As you can see in the picture below, there are a higher execution-order at the sum as at the integrator.

I changed the continuous block integrator to an discrete, I put a memory block in the back-path, also an unit-delay-block. But nothing lead to success.

I hope you can give me some approaches to find out a workaround.

Regards
Alex

[image: algebraic loop]

Comment: Why do you need to specify block priorities in the first place?